# how to select the oldest or newest date using where?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Is it possible to use a WHERE statement to find the oldest or the newest date ? 
I mean something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees 
WHERE birth_date = MIN(birth_date);
```

I know this doesn't work, but I am asking if there is a syntax error or the whole idea is wrong.

Comment: Mysql <> SQL Server. Choose the one you are using

Comment: Why don't you use `ORDER BY`?

Comment: sorry brother, i just found out that Mysql and SQL server have different syntax, i always assumed that they are the same! 
in my case i am using Mysql, and now i have a clear idea why it didn't work, i just needed to add SELECT after '=' sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible(`ANSI SQL`)

```
SELECT * FROM employees 
WHERE birth_date = (select MIN(birth_date) from employees)
```

or You can use `TOP 1 with Ties`(`SQL SERVER`)

```
Select TOP 1 with TIES * 
FROM employees 
Order by birth_date ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple subselect for getting the value you need

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE birth_date = (select MIN(birth_date) from employess)
```

Comment: I don't think first and second will yield same result when you have `TIES`

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL**

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees 
ORDER BY birth_date ASC
LIMIT 1
```

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM employees 
ORDER BY birth_date ASC
```